# How might one set up a reverse proxy that cannot decrypt traffic?

Tags: node.js, ssl, server, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'd like to have a reverse HTTPS proxy that CANNOT decrypt proxied traffic (ie an HTTPS passthrough/tunnel). The idea is to run this proxy on a VPS and point a domain to it, allowing for the IP address of the origin server to remain unexposed while maintaining end-to-end encryption.

Is this possible? I could probably proxy requests without difficulty since the destination address in that direction is fixed, but proxying responses seems problematic given that the proxy would be unable to read the client IP within an encrypted response.

A potential solution is to have the origin server package the encrypted response and destination address in a request made to the proxy, but I am unsure as to how I might generate the encrypted request without sending it (using node.js, which is the application running on the origin server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I got that you want to listen to requests from your VPC server and pass the request to your other server which has to remain unexposed.

This can be configured with the web server which you are using for proxy ( considering AWS allows port forwarding from a VPN server to non-VPN server ).
I prefer doing this with **Nginx** as it is easy, open-source with less code and more functionality.
There is a concept of **load balancing** which does the same as you mentioned above.

steps :

1. Install Nginx and keep it active.
2. Create a new configuration file in **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled**
3. write the below code with modifications:

   http {
   upstream myapp1 {
   server srv1.example.com;
   server srv2.example.com;
   server srv3.example.com;
   }

   server {
   listen 80;

   ```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
    }
   ```

   }
   }

and at the place of `srv1.example.com` and `srv2.example.com` add the domain to which you want to redirect requests

4. Save the file and restart the Nginx
5. Boom!! it should redirect all incoming requests to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've been looking into nginx myself but it's unclear to me whether it is capable of also proxying the responses from the origin server. If it is, how does it identify the client/destination IP when the response is encrypted?

Comment: According to NGINX documentation, The first part of the response from a proxied server is stored in a separate buffer, the size of which is set with the proxy_buffer_size directive. This part usually contains a comparatively small response header and can be made smaller than the buffers for the rest of the response.

Comment: And If buffering is disabled, the response is sent to the client synchronously while it is receiving it from the proxied server. This behavior may be desirable for fast interactive clients that need to start receiving the response as soon as possible.

Comment: I actually just forgot that addressing information is stored in the TCP headers (which are unencrypted.) That was the source of my confusion. Thanks again.